# Потокобезопасность в стандартной библиотеке C++

Tags: c++, c++11

[Потокобезопасность в стандартной библиотеке C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c9ceah3b.aspx)

> `shared_ptr`
>   Несколько потоков могут одновременно читать и записывать
>   разные объекты shared_ptr, даже если они являются копиями с одним
>   владельцем.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что имеется ввиду тот факт, что я могу из разных потоков создавать, например weak_ptr из shared_ptr и обратно, но никак не обращаться к объекту, на который указывает этот shared_ptr. Или все-таки потокобезопасным будет и непосредственно само обращение к объекту, на который указывает shared_ptr?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shared_ptr` гарантирует отсутствие гонок только для самого себя, а не для объекта на который он указывает.

Разумеется объект на который указывает `shared_ptr` можно читать из разных потоков, т.к. это не приводит к гонке.

Comment: Нетривиально то, что можно одновременно читать и писать без синхронизации. Ведь обычно после записи нужно обеспечить одинаковость вида разных потоков на память.

Comment: Ещё многие забывают, что модификация одного объекта `shared_ptr` из разных потоков - непотокобезопасная операция.